# Use whole path as parameter at routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, routes

I want to have a route, in whichs all string after '/' will be a parameter.

For example, if url is `localhost:3000/posts/1/edit` then `params[:path]` should be equal to 'posts/1/edit'

I've tried to do something like this

```
  resource :item, path: '/:path', only: [:show, :update, :create, :destroy], constraints: { path: /.+/, format: :json }
```

But in this case if I have .json at the end it is also included to a path param. I've tried another regex at constraint `/.+\./` but it doesn't work either.

What I am doing wrong? Thanks is adnvance!

Comment: Why do you need this in another param? You can already do `request.env["PATH_INFO"]` in a controller to get the same result (although it will have the beginning forward slash which you can easily get rid of).

Comment: @Pavel "Yo dawg", I heard you like regexing :path, so I changed :path to :_path, so you could have :path while you're regexing :_path

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, get it with `env['PATH_INFO']` instead of `params[:path]`

Answer (score 0):

```
# SoAwesomeMan
# Rails 3.2.13
Awesome::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :items, path: ':_path', _path: /[^\.]+/
  # http://localhost:3000/posts/1/edit.json?q=awesome
  #   => {"q"=>"awesome", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"items", "_path"=>"posts/1/edit", "format"=>"json"}
end 

class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :defaults
  def defaults
    case request.method
    when 'GET'
      case params[:_path]
      when /new\/?$/i then new
      when /edit\/?$/i then edit
      when /^[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/?$/ then show
      else; index
      end
    when 'POST' then create
    when 'PUT' then update
    when 'DELETE' then destroy
    else; raise(params.inspect)
    end
  end

  def index
    raise 'index'
  end

  def show
    raise 'show'
  end

  def new
    raise 'new'
  end

  def edit
    raise 'edit'
  end

  def create
    raise 'create'
  end

  def update
    raise 'update'
  end

  def destroy
    raise 'destroy'
  end
end
```